# How to password protecting url in IIS

Tags: iis, iis-8

I want to set username and password to some URLs in iis. i tried to use basic authentication to password protecting url but i couldn't.
I'm using asp.net MVC and i have an area with some controllers

for exp, i want to set password for

```
example.com/sec/
```

and

```
example.com/test/test
```

that

```
/test/
```

is a controller in area. how can i create own username and password and set them for some URLs

and how can i enable basic authentication for area directories

Comment: You might get some ideas from https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/development/dotnet-development/thoughts-on-asp-net-mvc-authorization-and-security/

Comment: As far as I know, it’s not possible password protecting url in IIS, maybe you can find a way in mvc.

Comment: @samwu so Plesk how can do it in windows server

Comment: Plesk uses php, but what you mentioned above is asp.net MVC, what kind of project are you?

Comment: My project is asp.net MVC and to control windows server, i used of Plesk. in Plesk you can password protecting url and directories. i changed my server and in the new server i didn't install plesk @samwu

Comment: It is difficult to slove your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.